# Preventing playing an MP3 file using an HTML anchor

Tags: html

How do you make an MP3 link download instead of play "in-browser"?

I tried changing the target to blank, but that just opened the player in a new window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this by modifying the link.  You will have to have the HTTP server that serves the file send a `Content-Type` of "application/octet-stream".  Presumably it is sending the type "audio/mpeg", which is hinting to the browser that it is MP3 content.  Without the capacity to alter this header, you can't achieve this.

Comment: Yep, also the `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` headers (and possibly more).

Comment: Nod.  `Content-Disposition` can effectively force browsers (or try to anyway... not all browsers will play nice) to download a file, regardless of the `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 3):

If your server supports PHP, create a PHP script called "getfile.php" (or similar) that takes a parameter of a file ID or file name. Set the `content-type` and `content-disposition` headers within the script to force a download prompt.

See: http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm

Comment: Can you summarise here? What does it actually do? What kind HTML and HTTP headers are send/used?

Answer (score 2):

Lots of solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=force+download).  Here's the basic idea:

- Use Javascript to make a (ajax) request to the server
- When the request is received, run a script
- This script redirects your browser temporarily to a new page
- The new page has a few headers telling your browser to expect a file attachment, and what kind of attachment it is
- The "save as" dialog pops up and your original page is still onscreen

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I've seen people with the same problem before just with other file types, they used the code below:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:mp3)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

For quite some time (Chrome 14+, Firefox 20+, Edge 44+) it is possible to use the [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) on same-origin links to force download behavior even when the server doesn't supply a `Content-Disposition` header on the link target.

Answer (score -1):

Without access to the server generating the HTTP responses, the browser gets to decide what to do with different types of responses. usually the only files a browser will download are things like `.zip` files which it cannot display.

Comment: Yes but assuming no server access, the user agent is the only thing that gets to decide what to do with the response.